# php generate html pages from string

Tags: php, html

I have this script to generate static html pages for each store location the company has from a .xls list, then the script encodes urls after store location based on a keyword string.

as it is currently:

```
keyword_string = "key1 key2 key3 key4 key5";

function urlX($location) {
        return $this->xURL($location).'/'.urlencode($this->keyword_string).'.html';
    }
```

How can I make it read 2 or even 3 variations of the keyword_string  and randomize the html urlencode?

Comment: What do you mean exactly by randomizing the html urlencode? urlencode is a function which returns a string and takes another string as parameter, what do you want to randomize?

Comment: Are you looking to generate a link with a random key picked from $keyword_string?  This can be done by creating an array and choosing a random key.

Comment: @AndreiCristianProdan The script is currently creating same url for each location like this:

location1/key1+key2+key3.html 
location2/key1+key2+key3.html

And I am trying to make it do is:

location1/key1+key2+key3.html 
location2/key3+key1+key2.html
location3/key2+key1+key3.html

Etc.. 

user1145643 Can you give me an example how will I implement it into the script ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will create truly random links.  If you wish to have a set number of keyword_string sets (ie: keyword_string_1 = "key1 key2 key3", keyword_string_2 = "key2 key3 key1", etc...) and choose a random set to attach to each location, this method can be used on a more simple scale.  There are probably several ways to speed this up as well.

```
$keyword_string = "key1 key2 key3 key4 key5";

function urlX($location) {
   global $keyword_string;
   $keyword_string = @explode(" ", $keyword_string);
   if(is_array($keyword_string)){
      $total = count($keyword_string);
      $random_keys = Array();
      for($i=0; $i<$total; $i++){
         $new = rand(0,$total-1);
         while(in_array($new,$random_keys)){
            $new = rand(0,$total-1);
         }
         array_push($random_keys, $new);
      }
   }
   $page = "";
   foreach($random_keys as $key){
      $page .= $keyword_string[$key] . " ";
   }

   return $location . "/" . urlencode(trim($page)) . ".html";

}
```

ADDED NEW:

Here's the above code adapted to a set amount of random strings.  You can pre-load additional strings and add them to the end of the `$keyword_string` Array.

```
$keyword_string_1 = "key1 key2 key3 key4 key5";
$keyword_string_2 = "key2 key3 key4 key5 key1";
$keyword_string_3 = "key3 key4 key5 key1 key2";

/// ADD MORE HERE IF YOU LIKE
$keyword_string = Array($keyword_string_1, $keyword_string_2, $keyword_string_3); 

function urlX($location) {
   global $keyword_string;
   if(is_array($keyword_string)){
      $total = count($keyword_string);
      $random_keys = Array();
      $page = $keyword_string[rand(0,$total-1)];
   }
   return $location . "/" . urlencode(trim($page)) . ".html";
}

print urlX("http://www.google.com"); /// SIMPLE CALL TO NEW FUNCTION urlX()
```

ADDED NEW:

```
$keyword_string_1 = "key1 key2 key3 key4 key5";
$keyword_string_2 = "key2 key3 key4 key5 key1";
$keyword_string_3 = "key3 key4 key5 key1 key2";

function urlX($location) {
global $keyword_string_1, $keyword_string_2, $keyword_string_3;    

    if($location == "http://www.url1.com"){ /// CHANGE THESE TO ACTUAL URLS
        return $location . "/" . urlencode($keyword_string_1) . ".html";
    }else if($location == "http://www.url2.com"){
        return $location . "/" . urlencode($keyword_string_2) . ".html";
    }else if($location == "http://www.url3.com"){
        return $location . "/" . urlencode($keyword_string_3) . ".html";
    }else{
        return false;
    }

}

print urlX("http://www.url1.com");
```

Comment: Yes I think that to be able to choose from a number of pre set keyword_string options will be a better way to go as I have a bit more control.

Comment: @user1154643 Can you tell me how do I go about implementing it in the script?

Comment: @user1154643 This makes it randomize the link however every time the page is refreshed there is a new set of links, it should only randomize it once, also instead of location name it prints Array:
http://127.0.0.1/Array/key1+key2+key3+key4+key5.html

Comment: @user1154643  I managed to adapt it to the script so now the city name works fine, just the random links keep changing every time you refresh the page

Comment: Also there is a very weird problem, it will load the page regardless of you url ie. you+can+put+here+whatever+you+want+and+the+page+still+loads.html

Comment: Of course it changes every time you refresh the page, it's random :)  If you don't want this, then all you needed from the beginning was to hard-code a set number of links.  If the same page still loads regardless of the .html file you are calling from the url, then there is more than likely something in your server's configuration that is silently forwarding a 404.

Comment: @user1154643 Yes you're right, it was a server issue with .htaccess, what do you mean set number of links ?  Thanks

Comment: If each location correlates with a distinct .html page, just hardcode if/else statements to determine what the full url should be.  (ie: if location is $a, then return "http://location/a/url/here", else if location is $b, then return "http://location/b/url/here".)  If you need an actual code example let me know and I'll edit my answer.